# Spring <form:select initial value

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there a way of setting a initial value (One of x in the list) for a 
`<form:select` drop down similar to the text area default value?

i.e.

```
<td valign="top">
  <form:select id="${appNameFormId}" path="metadata.appName" items="${dbList}" 
               disabled="true" itemValue="appName" itemLabel="appName">
  </form:select>
</td>

<td valign="top">
  <TEXTAREA id="${nameFormId}" name=jobName ROWS="1" COLS="25" >${job.jobName}
  </TEXTAREA>                                     
</td>
```

Comment: @marcind: Microsoft doesn't have a monopoly on the MVC pattern, you know.

Answer (score 2):

Because SELECT value comes from command object during rendering and go back to command object after submission I suggest to assign default value to metadata.appName inside Controller (manually or by using method with @ModelAttribute annotation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib).